# Почему выводится бесконечная вложенность тегов?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

При работе этого кода появляется такая вложенность. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

[image]

```
add_action('the_post', 'add_similiar_posts' ,10, 2);
function add_similiar_posts($tags)
{
  if (is_singular('post')) {
  global $post, $tags, $rand;
  echo '<div class="poxojie_zapisi">';
    echo '<h3>Похожие записи:</h3>';
      $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
      if ($tags) {
          $tag_ids = array();
          foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
                $args=array(
                  'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                  'caller_get_posts'=>1,
                  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                  'showposts'=> 5
                );
         $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
         if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
                  $my_query->the_post();
                  echo '<li><a href="';
                  the_permalink();
                  echo '">';
                  the_title();
                  echo '</a></li>';


      }
      echo '</ul>';
      echo '</div>';
      wp_reset_query();
      }
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Забыли весь блок внутри `foreach` обернуть в `{}`?

Comment: @Suvitruf, попробовал. Все также

Comment: Ужасный код. Ничего не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Аккуратное форматирование кода с использованием современных IDE позволяет избежать многих ошибок. Посмотрите на свой код в отформатированном виде

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'add_similiar_posts', 10, 2 );

function add_similiar_posts( $tags ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        global $post, $tags, $rand;
        echo '<div class="poxojie_zapisi">';
        echo '<h3>Похожие записи:</h3>';
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
        if ( $tags ) {
            $tag_ids = array();
            foreach ( $tags as $individual_tag ) {
                $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
            }
            $args     = array(
                'tag__in'          => $tag_ids,
                'caller_get_posts' => 1,
                'post__not_in'     => array( $post->ID ),
                'showposts'        => 5,
            );
            $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                echo '<ul>';
                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $my_query->the_post();
                    echo '<li><a href="';
                    the_permalink();
                    echo '">';
                    the_title();
                    echo '</a></li>';


                }
                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</div>';
                wp_reset_query();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь уже четко видно, что у вас `<div class="poxojie_zapisi">` не закрыт. Отсюда и проблема.

Сделайте так:

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'add_similiar_posts', 10, 2 );

function add_similiar_posts( $tags ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        global $post, $tags, $rand;
        echo '<div class="poxojie_zapisi">';
        echo '<h3>Похожие записи:</h3>';
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
        if ( $tags ) {
            $tag_ids = array();
            foreach ( $tags as $individual_tag ) {
                $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
            }
            $args     = array(
                'tag__in'          => $tag_ids,
                'caller_get_posts' => 1,
                'post__not_in'     => array( $post->ID ),
                'showposts'        => 5,
            );
            $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                echo '<ul>';
                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $my_query->the_post();
                    echo '<li><a href="';
                    the_permalink();
                    echo '">';
                    the_title();
                    echo '</a></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
                wp_reset_postdata();
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Я переставил закрывающий `</div>` ниже и заменил `wp_reset_query()`, который не рекомендован к использованию, на `wp_reset_postdata()`.